# How to choose matching layer sizes in a convolutional autoencoder?

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tf.keras, autoencoder

Are there any suggested best practices when choosing layer sizes when building a convolutional autoencoder?

For example, if I'm working with a `28x28x1` MNIST image, and creating my model with `tf.keras` how can I match up my `Conv2D` and `MaxPool2D` layers with `Conv2DTranspose` and `Upsampling2D` layers in order to return to a `28x28x1` image?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep the filter sizes same to yield the output with the same shape as input. If you have used 3x3 filters in Conv2D layer, then,  3x3 filters in Conv2DTranspose.

There is the choice of filter sizes you have, which in best practice are odd filters rather than even. So, 3x3(most common) and 5x5 can be used. You can also try 2x2 (an exception to the best practice but it has been used).